# Create chart using python

Tags: python, charts, image

I have a list of contents. Each content has a list of users who watched this content. I want to create a chart like in image below using Python.

I know that the radius of circle is proportional to the number of users who are watched content. The distance between circles is proportional to the number joint users.

So I'm interested in any variant of solving this problem (algorithm or existing package). Also, maybe somebody knows, how such charts are called (the cloud of links?).

[image]

Do you have any ideas how to make it?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [`networkx`](http://networkx.github.io/) or [`pyGraphviz`](http://networkx.lanl.gov/pygraphviz/)

Comment: When I've done work with data like this in the past, I just export it as JSON and visualize it with [d3](http://d3js.org).  In the d3 lexicon, you're looking at either a "force" or "pack" layout (the latter produces a "bubble chart").

Comment: Instead of using the javascript d3, you can use the python wrapper (or is it a port) d3py (https://github.com/mikedewar/d3py).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all responses. I think that it will be useful if I describe here the how I solve my problem.

Here is a bit of code. First, I clustered data using hierarchical/kmeans clusterization. Then I prepare a simple dictionary and convert it to d3-style json. Json is used with html from examples on http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063530.

```
#coding: utf-8
import argparse
import json
import logging
import sys
import numpy
import pylab
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from common import init_db_connection
from numpy import array
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy

logger = logging.getLogger("build2")

CLUSTERING_TYPE_KMEANS = "KMEANS"
CLUSTERING_TYPE_HIERARCHY = "HIERARCHY"

def get_coord_names(cursor, limit):
    sql = """
        SELECT DISTINCT unnest(user_ids) ivi_id
        FROM (
            SELECT user_ids
            FROM content_watched_by_users cw
                JOIN content c ON c.id = cw.content_id
            ORDER BY array_length(ivi_ids, 1) DESC
            LIMIT %s
        ) as t
        ORDER BY ivi_id;
    """
    logger.info(cursor.mogrify(sql, (limit,)))
    cursor.execute(sql, (limit,))

    coord_names = [x[0] for x in cursor]
    return coord_names


def get_matrix_of_observations_and_objects(cursor, coords_name, limit):
    sql = """
        SELECT c.title, user_ids
        FROM content_watched_by_users cw
            JOIN content c ON c.id = cw.content_id
        ORDER BY array_length(user_ids, 1) DESC LIMIT %s"""
    logger.info(cursor.mogrify(sql, (limit,)))
    cursor.execute(sql, (limit,))

    logger.info(u"Начинаем получать матрицу наблюдений и массив объектов")
    matrix = []
    objects = []

    for content_id, user_ids in cursor:
        logger.info(u"Обрабатывается %s", content_id)
        objects.append((content_id, len(user_ids)))

        row = [0] * len(coords_name)
        for user_id in user_ids:
            try:
                row[coords_name.index(user_id)] = 1
            except ValueError:
                logger.error(u"Что-то не так с user_ids %s", user_ids)

        matrix.append(row)
    logger.info(u"Матрица наблюдений и массив объектов получены")
    return array(matrix), objects


def fcluster_to_d3_dict(fcluster, objects, name_cluster=False):
    d = {"name": "", "children": []}
    for i in range(max(fcluster)):
        d["children"].append({"name": "", "children": []})

    for index, parent_id in enumerate(fcluster):
        parent = d["children"][parent_id - 1]
        parent["children"].append({"name": objects[index][0], "size": objects[index][1]})

        if name_cluster and not parent["name"]:
            parent["name"] = objects[index][0]
    return d


def code_to_d3_dict(code, objects, name_cluster=False):
    d = {"name": "", "children": []}
    for i in range(max(code) + 1):
        d["children"].append({"name": "", "children": []})

    for index, parent_id in enumerate(code):
        parent = d["children"][parent_id]
        parent["children"].append({"name": objects[index][0], "size": objects[index][1]})

        if name_cluster and not parent["name"]:
            parent["name"] = objects[index][0]
    return d


def save_to_json(result_dict, output_file="d3/flare.json"):
    logger.info(u"Перегоняем в JSON")
    f = open(output_file, "w")
    json.dump(result_dict, f)
    f.close()
    logger.info(u"JSON сохранен по адресу: %s", output_file)


def hierarchy_clustering(matrix, objects, threshold, name_cluster):
    Z = hierarchy.linkage(matrix, method='ward')
    fcluster = hierarchy.fcluster(Z, threshold, 'distance')

    hierarchy.dendrogram(Z)
    pylab.savefig("temp.png")

    logger.info(fcluster)
    result_dict = fcluster_to_d3_dict(fcluster, objects, name_cluster)
    return result_dict


def kmeans_clustering(matrix, objects, k, name_cluster=False):
    S = 1 - (matrix / numpy.max(matrix))
    db = KMeans(n_clusters=k).fit(S)
    logger.info(db.labels_)
    result_dict = code_to_d3_dict(db.labels_, objects, name_cluster)
    return result_dict


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=u'Скрипт для получения красивого графа')
    # БД
    parser.add_argument('--db_host', default="localhost", type=str, dest="db_host",
                        help=u'Хост БД, по умолчанию: localhost')
    parser.add_argument('--db_port', default="5432", type=str, dest="db_port",
                        help=u'Порт БД, по умолчанию: 5432')
    parser.add_argument('--db_name', default="da_test", type=str, dest="db_name",
                        help=u'Имя БД, по умолчанию: da')
    parser.add_argument('--db_user', default="da", type=str, dest="db_user",
                        help=u'Пользователь БД, по умолчанию: da')
    # общее
    parser.add_argument("--log-level", default='INFO', type=str, dest="log_level",
                        choices=['DEBUG', 'INFO', 'WARNINGS', 'ERROR'], help=u"Уровень логирования")
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--limit', required=True, type=int, dest="limit",
                        help=u'Количество контента в выборке. '
                              u'Контент осортирован по количеству просмотревших его пользователей')
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', required=True, type=str, dest="output_file_path",
                        help=u'Куда сохранять JSON-результат')
    parser.add_argument('-n', '--name_cluster', action="store_true", dest="name_cluster",
                        help=u'Именовать кластеры по первому элементу в кластере')
    parser.add_argument("-c", "--clustering", default=CLUSTERING_TYPE_KMEANS, type=str, dest="clustering_type",
                        choices=[CLUSTERING_TYPE_KMEANS, CLUSTERING_TYPE_HIERARCHY], help=u"Тип кластеризации")
    # kmeans
    parser.add_argument('-k', '--max_k', type=int, dest="max_k",
                        help=u'Максимальное число кластеров. Только для kmeans')
    # иерархическая
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--threshold', type=float, dest="threshold",
                        help=u'Граница разделения на плоские кластеры. Только для иерархической кластеризации')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=getattr(logging, args.log_level), format="%(asctime)s :: %(message)s")

    connection = init_db_connection(args.db_host, args.db_port, args.db_user, args.db_name)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    coords_name = get_coord_names(cursor, args.limit)
    matrix, objects = get_matrix_of_observations_and_objects(cursor, coords_name, args.limit)
    connection.close()

    if args.clustering_type == CLUSTERING_TYPE_KMEANS:
        result_dict = kmeans_clustering(matrix, objects, args.max_k, args.name_cluster)
    elif args.clustering_type == CLUSTERING_TYPE_HIERARCHY:
        result_dict = hierarchy_clustering(matrix, objects, args.threshold, args.name_cluster)
    else:
        raise Exception(u"Неизвестный тип кластеризации")
    save_to_json(result_dict, args.output_file_path)
```

Result looks like:

[image: KMeans clustering]